# different value of variable while inserting

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a pair of random numbers 1234567890-9876543210 (10 digits each)
I made this code. It works fine it generates a pair of random numbers BUT if I try to insert it into database I get same results multiple times. Let's say I get 1234567890 more than once. If I echo the insert statement I get different results but when I want to query it into database I get same results.

```
$numbers = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
srand(time());
$f = fopen('sql0.txt', 'w');

for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++)
{

   $r = NULL;
   $r2 = NULL;

   for($x=0;$x<10;$x++)
   {
       $n = rand(0,9);
       $r .= $numbers[$n];
    }

    for($x=0;$x<10;$x++)
    {
       $n1 = rand(0,9);
       $r2 .= $numbers[$n1];
    }

    echo("INSERT INTO ci_codes VALUES (NULL, '$r', '$r2', '0')<br>");

}
```

Comment: Do the columns support integers of that length? Also why are you trying to be clever generating the numbers and don't just use `mt_rand(min,max)`?

Comment: columns are set as int(10) max value of variable can be 999999999 tho, what type should I use?

Comment: But the table columns are integer, so they get converted.

Comment: Not related, but isn't `$numbers[$n]` the same thing as `$n`? Why do you need the array?

Comment: Can you post the version of the script that tries to insert instead of just printing?

Comment: the thing is I need generate a milion of codes and I do not know whether I would not get same entries with mt_rand

Comment: Also the problem was with the type of columns I changed it to bigint and it is working now. Just have problems with time of generating the numbers.. any solutions ? Should I run it in webserver or localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the INSERT expression inside your loop? That might cause the trouble.

As others have mentioned, it is better to just generate the numbers once with the php function, then run your MySql Query.

```
$r = mt_rand(0, 10000000);
$r2 = mt_rand(0, 10000000);

echo("INSERT INTO ci_codes VALUES (NULL, '$r', '$r2', '0'");
```